# batch command to move folders containing files

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos, synology

I'm trying to write a bat file which will help me sorting folders on my synology. I'm downloading files to folder "downloads", after unziping they are folders. For example.

I have a folders containing files

```
\downloads\folder1\file1.txt
\downloads\folder2\file2.jpg
\downloads\folder3\file3.txt
```

I want to batch sort only folders with txt file and move them to other folder
so for example folder with txt files will go to

```
\folders with txt\folder1\file1.txt
\folders with txt\folder3\file3.txt
```

that's my first problem, and the second one is how to mount synology main directory using pushd command, I know how to mount /downloads/ but have no idea how to mount main catalog.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`for /d %%A in (*) do` will search for folders in the current directory.

`dir /b %%A\*.txt >nul 2>&1 && echo %%A` will print folder name if there are any `.txt` files in that folder.

To move folders with `.txt`

```
for /d %%A in (*) do (
    dir /b %%A\*.txt >nul 2>&1 && move %%A "folders with txt"
)
```

Comment: Concerning your second problem - be more specific. What do you mean `to mount using pushd`? `pushd` is the command to save and then change the current directory.

Comment: 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I can't go to catalogs on Synology using simple cd command so when I use pushd network location is recognized as a temporary disk. Y:/ for example, but I need to command it using existing directory such as pushd /NAS/downloads, I can't do it just for /NAS/

Comment: If you need to `cd` to UNC path - `pushd \\server\share` then execute a script as in the current dir. If you need to pass UNC path use `net use x: \\server\\share` then use `x:\\`.

Comment: Ok it works but some folders with txt were skipped, I have no idea why :(

Comment: Execute `dir /b *.txt || echo fail` in that folders and see the message.

Comment: Executing dir /b *.txt || echo fail in that folders the answer is File not found fail and I've checked that there are still txt files in downloads folder

using net use x: \\server\\share answer is system error 85 and name of device is already in use